# ElectronJS Webview cookies not getting cleared

Tags: javascript, electron

I am not able to clear the cookies of a website in Webview.

I tried to clear storage using -

```
let session=require('electron');
  session.clearCache(function () {
    //   console.log("cache clear");
     });
    session.clearStorageData();

 session.defaultSession.cookies.get({}, (error, cookies) => {
  cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
    let url = '';
    // get prefix, like https://www.
    url += cookie.secure ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    url += cookie.domain.charAt(0) === '.' ? 'www' : '';
    // append domain and path
    url += cookie.domain;
    url += cookie.path;

    session.defaultSession.cookies.remove(url, cookie.name, (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(`error removing cookie ${cookie.name}`, error);
    });
  });
});
```

Then I tried to clear cookies of webview by accessing `getWebContents()` but 'getWebContents()' is not available on console when I tried. How to access the webview and then clear session so that next user can't login with the last user's creds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this see [source](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#sesclearstoragedataoptions-callback)

```
electronConstants().mySession.clearStorageData([], function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```